# LeetCode 189 - Rotate Array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, interview-questions

I have a working solution for this problem that was accepted in LeetCode:

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative."

```
function rotate(nums, k) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= k; i += 1) {
    const poppedNum = nums.pop();
    nums.unshift(poppedNum);
  }

  return nums;
}

// rotate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3) -> [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Questions:

- Would the time complexity be \$O(k)\$ and space complexity be \$O(1)\$?
- Is there a better way to solve this? The question asked to rotate the elements in-place if possible, but I am not sure how to accomplish this at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Review

Not bad, but there is room for a few improvements to avoid some possible problematic input arguments.

### Style

Some points on your code.

- The names `nums` and `k` could be better, maybe `array` and `rotateBy`
- Try to avoid one use variables unless it makes the lines using them to long. Thus you can pop and unshift in one line `nums.unshift(nums.pop());`
- Idiomatic javascript uses zero based loop counters rather than starting at 1. Thus the loop would be `for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {`

### Complexity

Your complexity is \$O(n)\$ and storage \$O(1)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of rotations, the range \$n>0\$

However consider the next examples

```
rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 18); // Will rotate 18 times same as rotate 0
rotate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 8); // Will rotate 8 times same as rotate left 1
rotate([1], 8e9); // Will spend a lot of time not changing anything
```

Your function will do too much work if the rotations are outside the expected ranges, the rotation can be done in reverse in less steps, or rotating has no effect.

You can limit the complexity to \$O(k)\$ where \$0<k<=n/2\$

### Rewrite

This is a slight improvement on your function to ensure you don't rotate more than needed.

```
function rotate(array, rotateBy) {
    rotateBy %= array.length;
    if (rotateBy < array.length - rotateBy) {
        while (rotateBy--) { array.unshift(array.pop()) }
    } else {
        rotateBy = array.length - rotateBy;
        while (rotateBy--) { array.push(array.shift()) }
    }
    return array;
}
```

**Update**

As vnp's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210537/120556) points out the complexity of `Array.unshift` and `Array.shift` is not as simple as \$O(1)\$ and will depend on the array type. We can assume the best case for this problem, sparse array (effectively a hash table) and thus will grow/shrink down at \$O(1)\$

In that case the function above has a mean complexity of \$O(log(n))\$ of all possible values of \$k\$

Note that if the cost of grow/shrink operations is \$O(n)\$ (dense array) this will add \$n\$ operations for each \$k\$ making the above \$O(kn)\$ with \$0<=k<(n/2)\$ Expressed in terms of \$n\$ or \$k\$ only it remains \$O(log(n))\$  or \$O(k)\$

---

You could also use Array.splice

```
 array.unshift(...array.splice(-rotateBy,rotateBy));
```

However under the hood the complexity would be a little greater \$O(2n)\$ (which is still \$O(n)\$) as splice steps over each item to remove and add to a new array. Then `...` steps over them again to `unshift` each item to the array.

The storage would also increase as the spliced array is held in memory until the code has finished unshifting them making storage \$O(n)\$

If the array contained all the same values the rotation would have no effect thus all rotation could be done in **O(1)**. However there is no way to know this without checking each item in turn.

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity really depends on the `unshift` time complexity. ECMA does not specify it, but I would expect that it is not constant. I would not be surprised if it is actually linear in the size of the array. If so, the complexity of `rotate` would be \$O(nk)\$.

In fact, I tested the performance of your code by timing your `rotate` by 1, for arrays of size from `100000` to `100000000`, doubling the size every time. The results (in milliseconds) are

```
1, 3, 8, 14, 29, 33, 69, 229, 447, 926
```

I did few runs, the exact numbers were different, but consistent. You can see that as size doubles the run time (at least) doubles as well.

And again, it was rotation by 1. Rotation by `k` will take proportionally longer.

---

There are few classic algorithms which perform the rotation in true \$O(n)\$ complexity, that is their execution time does not depend on `k`. One is extremely simple to code, but takes effort to comprehend. In pseudocode:

```
    reverse(0, k)
    reverse(k, n)
    reverse(0, n)
```

Notice that each element is moved twice. This is suboptimal. Another algorithm moves each element exactly once - right into the place where it belongs. I don't want to spoil the fun of discovering it. Try to figure it out (hint: it needs to compute `gcd(n, k)`).

---

That said, the leetcode problem only asks to print the rotated array. I would seriously consider to not actually perform rotation, but

```
    print values from n-k to n
    print values from 0 to n-k
```

It feels like cheating, but in fact it is valid, and sometimes very useful technique.

Comment: JS has two types of arrays, sparse and dense. There is no programmatic way to determine what an arrays type is. Sparse arrays use a cheap hash to locate items and thus would not suffer from the need to `memcpy` all items up/down one position when calling `Array.unshift` or `Array.shift` It is generally assumed that these operations are O(1). Array memory allocations are never single items but rather double array size, or wait and half. Using this scheme does make it possible to have an array that can grow in both directions at O(1). Whether  this is in fact done I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

#### Think twice before modifying function parameters

The posted code modifies the content of the input array `nums` and also returns it.
When a function returns something,
it can be confusing if it also modifies the input — a side effect.
Modifying the input and not returning anything (`void` in other programming languages) is not confusing.
I think it's important to make a conscious of choice between two non-confusing behaviors: either modify the input and return nothing, or not modify the input and return the result as a new object.

#### Insert `k` items at the start of an array in one step instead of one item in `k` steps

In most programming languages, and I think in the context of this exercise, "array" usually means a contiguous area of memory. Inserting an element at the start is implemented by copying existing elements to shift them in memory by 1 position.

For this reason, for a solution to the array rotation problem, I would avoid repeatedly inserting elements at the start of the array, to avoid repeated copying of elements. Even if arrays in JavaScript may behave differently, I would prefer a solution that doesn't raise questions about the potential underlying implementation of arrays, and looks objectively easier to accept.

That is, I would prefer to store `k` values in temporary storage, shift the other elements by `k` steps (iterating over them only once), and then copy back the `k` elements to the correct positions.

```
function rotate(nums, k) {
  k %= nums.length;
  const rotated = new Array(nums.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    rotated[i] = nums[nums.length - k + i];
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length - k; i++) {
    rotated[i + k] = nums[i];
  }
  return rotated;
}
```

This is \$O(n)\$ in both time and space.
The extra space is needed to avoid modifying the input.
If we preferred modifying the input,
then only \$O(k)\$ extra space would be needed,
for temporary storage of elements that would be overwritten.

#### Taking advantage of JavaScript's features

Slightly more expensive in terms of time and space,
but my preferred solution would make better use of the built-in functions on arrays in JavaScript than the version in the previous section,
in much more compact code:

```
function rotate(nums, k) {
  k %= nums.length;
  const m = nums.length - k;
  return nums.slice(m).concat(nums.slice(0, m));
}
```

Comment: Returned reference allows chaining. Caller can shallow `rotate([...array], 1)` Shallow copy within function means all outside references need updating, the caller may not be able to. Compare `const rotate= (k, n) => (k %= n.length ? n.unshift(...n.splice(-k, k)) : 0, n)` to your last "compact" function, its worst is 50% faster than your best and its best is an order of mag (1700%+) faster  than your best (not counting your funcs GC overhead). Google now rank pages in part on load speed, poor performing JS will cost rank points. The days of functional JS are finally over YA.